# in mysql ndbcluster, which port will ndbd listening on, and how to config it?

Tags: mysql

in mysql ndbcluster, which port will ndbd listening on, and how to config it?

I can use PortNumber in [MGMD] block to set the listening port for mgmd server.
But how to set the port for [NDBD] servers?
Seems it listen on random choosed ports?

Comment: perhaps better to ask here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Answer (score 0):

you can find the mysql cluster setup info in this blog:http://ma-learnings.blogspot.nl/2012/07/mysql-cluster-and-ubuntu-1204.html. By default, it will use port 3306. But you can set the port in my.cnf file.